# condense/simplify this jquery?

Tags: html, nested, toggle

I've got an awkward little toggle that I've built in jquery. It works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify/combine this into one? I'm using the class get the id (because it's a piece of multiple entries on the page with individual ids. It's to toggle between show/hide divs.)

Here's the script:

```
        $(".btn-full-detail").click(function() { 
    var divId = $(this).attr('id');
    var divId2 = $(this).attr('id') + '-opened';
    $("#" + divId).toggle();
    $("#" + divId2).toggle();
    // alert(divId);
});

 $(".close-detail").click(function() { 
    var divId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var divId2 = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('-opened', '');
    $("#" + divId).toggle();
    $("#" + divId2).toggle();
});
```

and for reference, here are the divs this will affect:

```
<div class="btn-full-detail" id="btn-full-detail-2">
    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#x-2" aria-expanded="false">SEE FULL DETAIL</a>
 </div>

<div class="active-detail" id="btn-full-detail-2-opened">
      <div class="print-detail"><a href="#">print</a></div>
      <div class="archive-detail"><a href="#">Archive?</a></div>
      <div class="close-detail"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#x-2">&times;</i></a></div>
</div>
```